# MYSQL - number of rows returned equals number of connections?

Tags: mysql

Does my query get sent to the database once and I get a list of all the results in one shot which I then loop through, or do I have to request the next row from the DB each time?

Essentially, does reducing the number of rows I expect to return mean less connections/calls to the DB meaning my DB will be able to handle more connections at once, or is the number of database connections not dependent on the number of returned rows?

Comment: No, rows returned are not individual connections. Under normal circumstances a connection returns the data as a set.  Of course, if your queries returned much more data than was actually needed, this could put a load on the server which would reflect as poorer performance. Generally speaking, get the data you need for your answer.

Comment: Whether the connection is dropped immediately after the query or not might depend on the architecture of your application or on the settings/capabilities of the middle tier that your application uses to actually connect to/communicate with the database. If the database component uses a server-side cursor for the result set returned, the connection may stay live all the time until you've finished working with the application or explicitly specified to close the connection.

Answer (score 0):

A connection survives until one of these:

- You explicitly call disconnect(), or
- Your program terminates, or
- A network glitch causes the disconnect.

Normally, you should code your app to connect *once* near the beginning and disconnect when finished.  (There are *rare* use cases for having multiple connections open at once.)

Most APIs have an obscure setting that determines whether you get all the rows (of a `SELECT`) in one "round trip" to the server, or whether they are fed to you individually (maybe in small chunks??) in many round trips.  There are advantages and disadvantages of either.  99.9% of the time, I am happy getting the entire resultset on one round trip, even if it is 100K rows.